# Is there a way to escape only the unicode characters present in a JSON Array Value in java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, unicode

I have String and need to provide it as JSON Array.

```java
String a ="[{\"a\":\"\u3002\"}]";
JSONArray test=new JSONArray(a);
```

On converting to JSON Array the Unicode character gets converted from the hexa decimal format and the JSON Array is obtained as `[{"a":"。"}]`.

But my requirement is I require the JSON Array only with Unicode value as `[{"a":"\u3002"}]`. How it can be achieved ? If this can be achieved by escaping the unicode value ,is there any way to escape only the special characters of JSON Array without parsing the entire JSON Array?

Comment: what about `"\\u3002"`?

Comment: This is a trick question - they are all unicode.

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam is there any utility function to perform the same ?

Comment: What do you consider a "special" Unicode character that would need escaping in Java strings? Aren't Java characters pretty much capable of representing anything that fits into UTF-16?